# Why does [std::is_move_assignable] not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
        std::unordered_multimap<int, string> m{ { 1, "hello" } };
        auto b = std::is_move_assignable_v<decltype(*m.begin())>;
        // b is true

        auto v = *m4.begin(); // ok
        v = std::move(*m4.begin()); // compile-time error
}
```

**Issue:**

> If `b` is true, then `v = *m4.begin();` should be ok.

**Question:**

> Why does `std::is_move_assignable` not behave as expected?

**Error messages: (Clang 3.8 + Visual Studio 2015 Update 3)**

> ```
> error : cannot assign to non-static data member 'first' with
> const-qualified type 'const int'
>               first = _Right.first;
>               ~~~~~ ^
>
> main.cpp(119,5) :  note: in instantiation of member function
> 'std::pair<const int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
> std::allocator<char> > >::operator=' requested here
>               v = *m4.begin(); // error
> ```

Comment: It's likely a bug with `std::is_move_assignable_v` of your implementation http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9DNHpi8cKFTF5uEH

Comment: @Danh had to say, before there was undefined behaviour in example, right now there is unexisting random access operator[] on multimap.

Comment: @paweldac It's run time undefined behavior, he asked why this code can't be compiled

Answer (score 6):

> If `b` is true, then `v = *m4.begin();` should be ok.

`v = *m4.begin();` is copy assignment, not move assignment. Move assignment is `v = std::move(*m4.begin());`.

But as T.C. points out and Yam Marcovic answered as well, your use of `std::is_move_assignable` is wrong, because `decltype(*m.begin())` is a reference type. You end up not quite checking for move assignability, and your check *does* end up right for `v = *m4.begin();`.

For move assignment, the check should be `std::is_move_assignable_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*m.begin())>>`.

Anyway, `is_move_assignable` doesn't try too hard to check whether the type is move assignable, it only checks whether the type reports itself as move assignable.

Given

```
template <typename T>
struct S {
  S &operator=(S &&) { T() = "Hello"; return *this; }
};
```

`std::is_move_assignable<S<int>>::value` will report `true`, because the signature `S<int> S::operator=(S<int> &&);` is well-formed. Attempting to actually call it will trigger an error, since `T()` cannot be assigned to, and even if it could be, it couldn't be assigned a string.

In your case, the type is `std::pair<const int, std::string>`. Note the `const` there.

`std::pair<T1, T2>` currently always declares `operator=`, but if either `T1` or `T2` cannot be assigned to, attempting to actually use it will produce an error.

Class templates may make sure that a valid signature of `operator=` is only declared if its instantiation would be well-formed to avoid this problem, and as also pointed out by T.C., [`std::pair` will do so in the future](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2729).

Comment: I have updated the code. Use `std::move(*m4.begin())` instead.

Comment: @xmllmx Please don't focus on a single sentence. It doesn't change the rest of my answer, which covers `v = std::move(*m4.begin());` already.

Comment: This is [LWG issue 2729](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2729). Also OP is using `is_move_assignable` wrong: that `decltype` returns a reference type.

Comment: @T.C. Huh. And `is_move_assignable` is well-defined for lvalue reference types, and actually ends up checking something different, something very close to whether the type is copy-assignable. Thanks, and for the link.

Comment: @T.C. I linked to https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/ rather than https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/ though; I like the idea of the latter, but if it needs to be updated manually, I worry that in the future it will end up outdated.

Comment: @hvd Mine is currently more up-to-date than LWG's official ones :) (They merged a few pull requests to the sources, but haven't yet updated the HTML version.) But link to whichever one you prefer - I created mine because I don't want to load lots of gigantic issue lists when I want to have many issues open at once.

Comment: @T.C. Sorry, I misread. The final sentence is not *intended* to be a complete sentence. I deleted my earlier comment.

Answer (score 3):

First, as `*begin()` [returns an lvalue reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), you're actually passing an lvalue reference to `std::is_move_assignable`, which is then implemented by means of `std::is_assignable<T&, T&&>`. Now, notice the forwarding reference there, which converts to an lvalue reference. This means that by asking `std::is_move_assignable<SomeType&>` you have effectively asked `std::is_assignable<T&, T&>`—i.e. copy-assignable. Granted, this is a bit misleading.

You might want to test this code to see my point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct S {
    S& operator=(const S&) = default;
    S& operator=(S&&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_move_assignable<S>::value; // 0
    std::cout << std::is_move_assignable<S&>::value; // 1
}
```

All that said, `*begin()` in this case returns a `pair<const int, string>&`, so it would not be any-kind-of-assignable anyhow, because you cannot assign to a `const int`. However, as @hvd pointed out, since the function is declared in principal in the `pair` template, the type trait does not understand that if it were ever generated into an actual function by the compiler, the latter would encounter an error.

Comment: Nice, I had missed this and had not seen your answer until T.C. pointed out the same thing. It's not quite the same as copy-assignable though. It's possible, but probably a very bad idea, to only have an `operator=` overload taking `S&`, which would make `S` not copy-assignable.

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing `.begin()` iterator of empty container is undefined behaviour.

Comment: That's not the question. The issue is a compile-time error, rather than runtime-error. I have updated the code to avoid distracting the focus.

Comment: @xmllmx If you have a build error, then you should *say* so, not ask why it doesn't "*behave* as expected". And of course include the full and complete error output in the question body.

Comment: @xmllmx unordered_multimap doesn't have random access operator[]. Please corrent your code once again.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in `map` for sure, in `unordered_multimap` there is no [] operator

Comment: @paweldac, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map has an example showing `m[0]` is allowed.

Comment: @xmllmx you are using  `std::unordered_multimap` not `std::unordered_map` in your code. It is even yours?

Comment: @paweldac My compiler indeed cannot compile `m[0] = "hello"`. I have revised the code. The documentation's example is wrong.